# How To change opacity of sprite during animation in cocos2d iphone? COCOS2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I want to change the opacity of sprite during repeat forever moving animation.

```
How can I solve this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it together with another action (your `CCRepeatForever`) you should use a `CCSpawn` action which is able to execute more than one action in the same moment, eg:

```
id action1 = [CCEaseOut actionWithAction:[CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.1 key:@"opacity" from:0 to:255]
id action2 = your movement action
id action3 = [CCSpawn actionOne:action1 two:action2];
id action4 = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:action3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating CCSprite.cpp file (inside folder 2d>sprite-nodes).
Search for this line:

> void Sprite::setSpriteFrame(SpriteFrame *spriteFrame)

In this method you should add:

```
if (_opacityModifyRGB) {
  updateColor();
}
```

And solved!
Now yo can set opacity to a layer and all animations added inside it conserve its opacity. Remember to add **`setCascadeOpacityEnabled(true);`** to the layer.

You can check this link for more information: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15696